# Add PHP Intranet Site to sharepoint

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, deployment, site-collection, content-deployment

I have been given files for a whole PHP Intranet portal to add to sharepoint and i have no idea how its done. The site runs on port 82. The database i'm using is MS-SQL server 2008. Can anyone help me out with the necessary steps? I'm a newbie to this

Comment: If you want to show .php web pages only, you can use web page viewer web part.

Comment: If you want to place a link to your PHP Portal in SharePoint, you can [Host PHP Applications on IIS](http://php.iis.net/).. And add a link in SharePoint. Otherwise Robert has answered your question

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri Currently there's another site running on localhost(port 80) on IIS server. Each time you open the index/home page on a web browser for the 1st time it asks for the sharepoint username and password. I want the same thing to happen with this other one..how do i go about it?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: Don't add php files to SharePoint. SharePoint is a platform on its on (based on .net and ASP.net) and hence if you want to migrate your intranet from php to SharePoint you would have to start from scratch

Comment: Currently there's another site running on localhost(port 80) on IIS server. Each time you open the index/home page on a web browser for the 1st time it asks for the sharepoint username and password. I want the same thing to happen with this other one..how do i go about it?